# Adding array elements recursively in javascript concatenates them

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to add elements of a 2 D array in javascript based on some logic using recursion. I am surprised to find that instead of adding the numbers it is concatenating them. I mean to say the contents of variable "sum" is not the sum but concatenation of elements. Can someone help me? Please tell me about the mistake I have committed.

```
var globearr=[];
var stock=0;
var sum=0;
var some=["3#44#75","21#98#60"];
leastAmount(some);
function recur(myArr,i,j,row,col){
    if(i===row-1&&j===col-1){

    sum=sum+myArr[i][j];
    globearr[stock++]=sum;
    return 0;
    }
    else if(i===row-1 && j!== col-1){

    sum=sum+myArr[i][j];
    recur(myArr,i,j+1,row,col);
    }
    else if(i!==row-1 && j=== col-1){

    sum=sum+myArr[i][j];
    recur(myArr,i+1,j,row,col);
    }
    else
    {

    sum=sum+myArr[i][j];
    recur(myArr,i,j+1,row,col);
    recur(myArr,i+1,j,row,col);
    }   
}

function leastAmount(input1)
    { //some code goes here setting up row and col and temparr[]//     
    var myArr=new Array(row);    
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
    myArr[i]=new Array(col);
    }  
    y=0;        
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){        
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            myArr[i][j]=temparr[y++];
        }
    }

    recur(myArr,0,0,row,col);
    var start=globearr[0];
    var count=globearr.length;
        for(i=1;i<count;i++){
        if(start>globearr[i])
        {
            start=globearr[i];
        }
        }

        alert(start);
}
```

Comment: Just from reading your code i don't really get what it's doing, but what i suspect may be wrong is if you're using the `+` operator and one of the operands is a string, they will concatenate instead of add. You can use `typeof` to check, or `parseInt()` to convert to number type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parseInt() for every Integral operation